# Getting an access token from Google Playground to test a project

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-drive-api

For a Google project app that i code with node js, I need to have the client access to upload a file into his drive. As I test my code, no file appears in my drive. It's probably because I run the thing with my service account. So what i did is that : as i have a client ID (with my email etc.) and key that I created with google, i uploaded the json that contains those informations :

```
    {
    "web": 
    {   
        "project_id":"",
        "private_key_id": "",
        "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        "client_email": "",
        "client_id":"",
        "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret":"",
        "redirect_uris":["https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"]
        }
    }
```

Obviously blank spaces aren't blank in my code.
I also handled, in the google console, the client API access and added the client with the  Drive API application.
As I run the thing in the terminal, I get this error in the terminal : 
"Error: No key or keyFile set."
Thanks ! In my js, I have access to the api and to my keys.json file containing the informations necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to upload a file to your / a user's drive with the service account - you need to give to the service account a) the scopes to access yours / the user's drive (implies domain-wide delegation) and b) either a reading permission to the file or enable [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegate-domain-wide-authority) so it acts on your / your user's behalf.
2. If you want to test a method (e.g. upload a file) without a service account, I recommend you to do it with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create).
3. If you want to test your code with your own credentials instead of the service account - the authentication process will be different, as well as the content of the required credentials.json file. You need to stick to the procedure and authorization process as outlined in the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) - you can download the correct credentials file directly by clicking the "Enable the Drive API" button in the quickstart documentation. The correct credentials.json file for running the code as you (opposed to service account) will be the following:

```
{
"installed":{
  "client_id":"XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "project_id":"XXX",
  "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_secret":"XXX",
  "redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]
  }
}
```

The private key (and key Id) is only necessary for service accounts.

Comment: Thanks ! That helped a lot, I used the third method and it worked perfectly.